# Turning off auto-styling for Web Form designer in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Whenever you are in design mode in VS2012 for editing a Web Form, if you click on anything, and accidentally drag and drop, a CSS auto-style will appear at the top of the HTML for the aspx page.

From some preliminary research, I checked the following:
Tools>Options>HTML Designer>CSS Styling>Style Application Mode, but it was already set to manual. Is there somewhere else I should be looking to disable this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there is no way to turn off this. We have received this feedback through [connect link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735863/css-files-are-automatically-formatted). Please add vote to this connect bug. And we will consider this in future release of VS.

Comment: This connect issue - regarding CSS - doesn't seem related to the actual issue with the ASPX file.

Answer (score 2):

I also found this, and I have assoicated it rightly or wrongly, with large pages getting totally corrupted (table cell contents being apparrently randomly swapped).

I managed to turn autostyle off by going to Tools>Options>HTML Designer>CSS and selecting 'CSS (inline styles)' for each of the items there.

Autostyling has stopped and (fingers crossed) my latest pages have retained their integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options > Web Forms Designer > CSS  change all CSS(classes ) to CSS(inline styles)